# how do i ensure that matlab is calling the correct function when the same function is imported in multiple toolboxes

Tags: matlab

```
tau = 5;
K = 2;
A = -1/tau;
B = K/tau;
C = 1;
D = 0;

sys = ss(A,B,C,D)
Undefined function 'ss' for input arguments of type 'double'.

 >> which -all ss
 /Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/toolbox/ident/ident/
  @idParametric/ss.m           % idParametric method
 /Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/toolbox/shared/controllib/engine/
  @StaticModel/ss.m            % StaticModel method
 /Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/toolbox/signal/signal/
 @dfilt/ss.m                   % dfilt method
```

the function ss appears to be imported in 3 toolboxes. 
not sure what the problem is here, ive tried reseting the path to default, removing the toolbox function from the path, etc.

Comment: What do you expect/want this to do? As it stands it will only call one of the functions you mention (actually object methods) if you pass in one of the objects.

Comment: justin, thanks for the quick reply. i was working through a statespace (ss.m) example and could not get the correct result. it turns out that  did not have the control system toolbox loaded

Answer (score 1):

`ss` is a *method* that is defined for the various classes (`idParametric`, `StaticModel` and `dfilt`). Which version of `ss` is called depends on the class of the first input to the function. For example if you have have an `idParametric` object named `obj`, `ss(obj)` or `ss.obj()` will call the `ss` method that is defined for that specific class. In this way, you can have a single function name which behaves differently for different datatypes or objects.

If your case, your first input is of class `double` for which the `ss` method is *not* defined resulting in an error.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. it turns out that i did not have the control system toolbox loaded